# php adding arrays makes result empty

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, insert

I am filling an array with years of page publish dates. Then I make it have only unique years. Then I just need to insert a string as the first element for a select box. The resulting array should look like: ['Any', '2010', '2018', '2019', '2020'] for example. Before I insert the 'Any', I have the list of years. But when I add the 'Any', it somehow removes all years and just leaves the word. Can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
$years = array();
$post_list = Post::getPostList();
if (!empty($post_list)) {
    foreach ($post_list as $post){
        $years[] = $dh->formatDate($post->getTimestamp(), '~yyyy', 'system');
    }
    $years = array_unique($years, SORT_NUMERIC);
}                                 // all good up to here
$years = [t('Any')] + $years;     // and this removes the years
return $years;
```

Comment: Assuming `t('Any')` is some form of translation function which returns a string, why not use `array_push($years, t('Any'))`?. Or does array_push also give undesired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [this user comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php#86379) in the PHP docs, the union operator creates a union based on keys and not based on values.

Therefore if you do something like this:

```
$arr = ['2010', '2020', '2030'];
$years = ['Any'] + $arr;
var_dump($years);

// output
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Any"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "2020"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "2030"
}
```

The keys of the values in `$arr` are 0, 1, 2 - and the only key in `$years` is 0. This leads to the key being overwritten.

You can however use [array_unshift](http://php.net/array_unshift):

```
$arr = ['2010', '2020', '2030'];
array_unshift($arr, 'Any');
var_dump($arr);

// output
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "Any"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "2010"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "2020"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "2030"
}
```

or [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge):

```
$arr = ['2010', '2020', '2030'];
$arr = array_merge(['Any'], $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Note that the latter only works if your values are really strings since `array_merge()` has its own weird behaviour when merging number values.

Comment: I got it. As soon as I did $years = array('') it was working fine. As you said, the array's 0 index was not initialized and then overwritten by the 'Any' item. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [array_unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unshift.php):

```
array_unshift($years, t('Any'));
```

Pay attention array passed by reference, so you dont need to reasign the variable.

Comment: I did, same thing - adding the 2 arrays removes the years

Comment: What the return value of `t('Any')`?

Comment: t('Any') is just a string, t() function is for translation, you can assume it's just 'Any'.